# How to resolve the dependences issue while working in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, rpa

I am using the latet Robot Framework version 6.1 but when i installed **rpaframework** then it uninstalled robotframework version 6.1 and installed version 5.0.1.

When i again upgrade robotframework to version 6.1 then it shows dependences issues

**rpaframework 23.4.0 requires robotframework!=4.0.1,<6.0.0,>=4.0.0, but you have robotframework 6.1 which is incompatible.**

**rpaframework-pdf 7.1.5 requires robotframework!=4.0.1,<6.0.0,>=4.0.0, but you have robotframework 6.1 which is incompatible.**

**rpaframework-windows 7.3.2 requires robotframework!=4.0.1,<6.0.0,>=4.0.0, but you have robotframework 6.1 which is incompatible.**

Comment: It's seems that robotframework 6.1 isn't supported yet by these libraries. Solution would be to downgrade robotframework to 6.0 and report issue (If not already reported) to the developers of these libraries.